# Question about domains in complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

For each of the functions below, describe the domain of definition that is understood

a) $f(z)=1/(z^2+1)$, b) $f(z)=1/arg(z)$, c) $f(z)=z/(z+ \overline{z})$, d) $f(z)=1/()1-|z|^2$

a)$z \neq i,-i$
b) The answer is $Re_z \neq 0$. I can't understand why
c)$Re_z \neq 0$
d)$|z| \neq 0$

How does that look?. For the ones I answered, do you get the same answer?

Comment: For b), $\arg(z)\ne 0$ is equivalent to $\text{Im}(z)\ne 0$.

Comment: How exactly do you define $\arg z$?

Comment: it's the argument of z. It's basically an angle $\theta$ from the positive real axis to the angle in a way that $ -pi\leq \theta \leq pi$

Comment: * to the complex number

Comment: @TheMathNoob [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis) There is a big difference between argument of a complex number and the principal argument of a complex number.

Comment: ok, so if the real part is 0 then the argument(z) is either pi/2 or -pi/2.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasoning for b)

Firstly note that the $arg(z)$ function is defined for $\Bbb C - \{(0,0)\} $

Secondly for $z$ lying on the positive Real axis, the argument is $0$ so $f(z)=\frac{1}{arg(z)}$ will be undefined for $z$ lying on the positive real axis. Thus domain of $f$ must be $\Bbb C -\{z \in \Bbb C:Re(z)\ge 0$ and$ Im(z)=0\}$

The above reasoning holds if you are talking about the $arg(z)$ in the usual sense.

Comment: This is not correct. For $z$ on the *negative* real axis (e.g. $z=-1$) the argument can be $\pi + 2 k \pi$, but definitely not zero.

Comment: @MartinR Overlooked the possibility that you pointed out. I have made the required edits. Thank You.